# WP7 Listbox how UI virtualization work

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory-leaks, observablecollection, virtualizingstackpanel

I'm using ListBox which has `VirtualizingStackPanel`, which is said to support UI virtualizing by default.

However, when I set my **listStudent** (of type `ObservableCollection`, and have 5 Students in it) as `ItemsSource` for my `Listbox`. Then whenever user scroll to the end, I add another 5 Students to my **listStudent** (and of course UI is notified). But I see that memory consumed keep increased. There's no different from `StackPanel` in term of memory

How UI virtualization work? How to keep memory low when adding new item to **listStudent**?

Comment: OS preloads 3 size of a screen (?). Can you add more students (100 for example) to see the difference?

Comment: @Ku6opr I add 5 student many times, so when my listStudent.Count reach over 100, I scroll up. The ListBox virtualization mechanism MUST destroy those ListBoxItem which is not in screen. But it doesnot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

virtualization means list do not construct the list items which you have not scroll to yet.

so you can put your test code to item's loaded function or used converter code. you can see  whether virtualization works

for example

you can bind a converter to student's name prop and you can log it .then you know when the item create indeed

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you don't modified `ListBox` `ItemsPanel` that destroys UI virtualization

Answer (score 0):

Sheldon_Xiao on has pointed out some references on MSDN that [helpfully explain UI virtualizartion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/ad722b94-851a-4396-9f18-2fba144fd678)