# How to display a list of data in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have around 100 data in my list.
I need to display the list, it would be easy if i could display the list by fixing a frame for a single cell and reuse it...
This is possible in 'ios'.
Is it possible in windows phone??
If so could you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for virtualization. In a short, it keeps in memory only items you're going to render.

http://shawnoster.com/2010/08/improving-listbox-performance-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-data-virtualization/

[WP7 Listbox how UI virtualization work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377872/wp7-listbox-how-ui-virtualization-work)

PS: if you're looking for out-of-box solution, take a look at [Telerik Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx). [Here is documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/raddataboundlistbox-features-virtualizingdatacollection.html) about [virtualization](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/databoundlistbox.aspx). It allows to keep in list thousands of items and render them smoothly. I'm using it for a several months, controls are of high quality + support is lightspeed fast.